# Concatenating histograms in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am a new to MATLAB.  I have 6 histograms which are created from subdividing the image into patches.  How I can merge these patches to make one histogram (i.e. concatenating the 6 histograms)?

I have tried this code:

```
subplot(3,4,1) 
imhist(Patch1)
subplot(3,4,2) 
imhist(Patch2)
subplot(3,4,3) 
imhist(Patch3)
subplot(3,4,4) 
imhist(Patch4)
```

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate images or to concatenate histograms?

Comment: @VictorMay - The OP wishes to calculate a single histogram that expresses the intensity levels of all of the patches put together.  "Concatenating" is a misnomer here on the OP's part.  I would say that this is **merging** all of the information from all of the patches together.

Comment: Then why subdivide the image into patches in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate all of the patches into a single vector, then call `imhist` on this vector.  You mentioned that you have **six** histograms when your code is only showing **four**.  As such, I will assume that the other histograms come from `Patch5` and `Patch6`.  Knowing this, the code would simply be:

```
patch = [Patch1(:); Patch2(:); Patch3(:); Patch4(:); Patch5(:); Patch6(:)];
imhist(patch);
```

Histograms are agnostic with the dimensions of the image you're looking at.  It simply counts how many pixels you encounter per intensity level of the data you are using.  As such, we can simply put all of these pixels for each patch into a single vector and do a histogram of that vector.  This will work nicely as this will disregard the dimensions of each patch so we don't have to construct a new image and do a histogram of the newly constructed image.

Comment: @user3777182 - You're welcome. If I have helped you in any way, please consider accepting my answer.  Click on the checkmark icon at the top of my post on the left, beneath the up and down arrows.